# What type of data is in MessageBoxButton.Ok and MessageBoxButton.OkCancel?

Tags: vb.net, predefined-variables

If I wanted to send either MessageBoxButtons.Ok or MessageBoxButtons.OkCancel to a MessageBox and I wanted to store the correct value in a variable, to what type should I Dim it?

```
Dim MyVariable As ______ 
If <condition> Then
   MyVariable = MessageBoxButtons.Ok
Else
   MyVariable = MessageBoxButtons.OkCancel
End If

MessageBox.Show("Message", "Title", MyVariable)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like VBA. The messagebox show function is `MsgBox` and the buttons are specified with the `VbMsgBoxStyle` enum. If this is .NET you can dim as MessageBoxButtons. If this is VBA you can dim as `VbMsgBoxResult`

Comment: Actually it is Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2010 but I didn't see an appropriate tag and I'm not big enough to make a new one.  :-/

Comment: You have the right tag - `VB.Net` is what your after.

Comment: It is an enum, MessageBoxButton type.  You should not worry about that and let the compiler *infer* the type.  So you can simply write *Dim*.  It the option isn't on yet then, perhaps, you need to put `Option Infer On` at the top of the source code file.  That option has been turned on for quite a while already, all you could do wrong is using an ancient version of VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If MessageBox.Show("some text", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
  'they picked ok
End If
```

Or:

```
Dim result As DialogResult
result = MessageBox.Show("some text", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
```

Comment: If I used the 2nd way, I could later do: If result = DialogResult.Cancel then... ?

Comment: Am I seeing a pattern here? If I want to store a constant that's in the form: somename.option,  I dim the variable as somename?

Comment: Yes you can store a class level variable by the datatype you need then set it later and call it whenever/wherever since it does not lose it's scope.